# how to use image as a theme 

Tags: android

I need to use perticular image as the theme for my most of the activities in my application...
please help me how to do this..

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is to define and apply the custom style of your Activities in Res files. [Tutorial here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Answer (score 0):

if your using XML display there is a field background

@drawable/custom_dialog_background

or

android:background in the XML anchors

setBackgroundResource(int) in your code

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background

Comment: In that way i need to put that for every activity.. , instead i need to create a theme that I can use it in <application> tag if my total application need same theme  or in <activity> tag prescribed windows.